# Google Compute Engine Tesla K80 correct image

Tags: google-compute-engine, multi-gpu

I am using Google compute Engine to do some ML.  I want 8 GPUs and the cheapest is the Tesla K80.
I have tried many combinations of image and found every time that the GPUs are Unclaimed and so nothing works.  I see there are ML specific images, some debian 10 some debian 11.  What is even just one image that will work out of the box with the Tesla K80 VM?  I want all the GPUs working out of the box.  Is this even possible?  Do you always have to configure the GPUs?  Once you have the right image that matches correctly with the K80, what do you need to do to get those GPUs claimed and working?

Comment: The cheapest GPU is not necessarily the best one to use. The application that you are running must recognize the attached GPUs. You do not have a problem (yet) with Google Cloud. Note: are you sure you have allocated 8 GPUs? That requires a quota increase. Did you ask for one or verify that you have a quota for at least 8 GPUs in the region you are creating the instance?

Comment: @JohnHanley hi, I did get my quota.  I fixed this by going to L4, but that costs 5 times more.  It would be helpful for a lot of people to get the K80 solution in easy steps.

Comment: That is a problem with your application and not Google Cloud. If your app does not have support for a GPU model, it won't work.